# How to change color of label text?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

In UIFont, I couldn't find a color property. What's the trick to make a font appear green, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the `textColor` property that belongs to `UILabel` -- `UIFont` depends on other classes (like `UILabel`) to provide other GUI-related properties, like the color of the text.

More info [here](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the color in a `UIFont`, you set the `UILabel`'s `textColor` property, which is a `UIColor`.